# Array Iteration and Incrementing with Easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, easing

I am trying to create a function that iterates over an array and increments the values by certain amounts. The amounts that the values are incremented by must decrease as the values get larger.

Consider the following:

```
// Before first iteration
['100','150','220','280','310','330']

// After first iteration
['106','155','224','283','312','331']

// After second iteration
['112','160','228','288','314','332']

// After third iteration (note the last item has been reset to 100)
['100','117','164','232','291','316']
```

In the example above, I used the incremental amounts of '6,5,4,3,2,1' but the problem with these numbers is that eventually they will catch up with each other. I am struggling to calculate the correct values to use that will ensure the values are closer together towards the end of the array but the values do not ever overlap with each other.

**Just to reitorate, the issue here is not necessarily creating the array of values, it is creating an array of values that maintain the easing I want i.e. The rings get closer together towards the edge of the screen, whilst preventing the rings from eventually catching up with each other and overlapping....**

To complicate this further, whenever a value exceeds 332, it needs to be reset to 100. This will essentially move any rings on the outside, back to the inside...

These values will eventually form the base of a function that will create something like the following:

[image: Circles Example]

The incremental amounts will be the amounts to animate the sizes of the rings. I would have written the animation in CSS but unfortunately the animation will be event driven and by event driven I mean multi-touch event driven so JavaScript is my only option...

### My Code

I have already played around with a lot of code but I am really struggling to get my head around the algorithm and values! This is what I currently have but it is doesn't work correctly:

```
// Calculate the properties for each ring
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    var ring_decrement = 6-i;
    ring_properties[i].dimension += ((-2.5 * ((t=(ring_decrement/10)-1)*t*t*t - 1) + 0.1)/100)*container_width;
    ring_properties[i].opacity = i===0 ? 0 : i===1 ? 0.7 : Math.round((0.6-(i/10))*10)/10;
    if(((ring_properties[i].dimension/container_width)*100)>80){
        ring_properties[i].dimension = 100;
        ring_properties[i].opacity = 0;
    }
}
ring_properties.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.dimension===b.dimension){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return (parseInt(a.dimension)<parseInt(b.dimension)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
// Apply the properties to the rings
$('.radius_ring').each(function(i){
    /*if(ring_properties[i].dimension===100){
        $(this).addClass('paused');
    }*/
    $(this).css({
        width: ring_properties[i].dimension+'px',
        height: ring_properties[i].dimension+'px',
        opacity: ring_properties[i].opacity
    });
});
```

And here is the code to create the initial rings (this code works!):

```
var ring_dimension_percent = 5;
var ring_explode_increment = 0;
var container_width = parseInt($('#scan_radius_container').css('width'));
var ring_properties = new Array();

// Explode radius rings on load
var ring_explode = setInterval(function(){
    // Calculate the percentage of the container width
    ring_dimension_percent = ring_explode_increment===0 ? ring_dimension_percent : Math.round(-75 * ((t=(ring_explode_increment/10)-1)*t*t*t - 1) + 10);
    // Translate the percentage into pixels
    ring_properties[ring_explode_increment] = {
        // Set the dimension
        dimension: (ring_dimension_percent/100)*container_width,
        // Set the opacity
        opacity: ring_explode_increment===0 ? 0 : ring_explode_increment===1 ? 0.7 :  Math.round((0.6-(ring_explode_increment/10))*10)/10
    };
    // Apply the styles to the radius rings
    $('.radius_ring:eq('+ring_explode_increment+')').css({
        width: ring_properties[ring_explode_increment].dimension+'px',
        height: ring_properties[ring_explode_increment].dimension+'px',
        opacity: ring_properties[ring_explode_increment].opacity
    });
    if($('.radius_ring').length===(ring_explode_increment+1)){
        clearInterval(ring_explode);
    }else{
        ring_explode_increment++;
    }
},50);
```

Comment: can you share the JSFiddle?

Comment: @QuinnDaley unfortunately I will not be able to get a jsFiddle working as my application requires a whole load of libraries of which dont seem to work with jsFiddle. I have tried including them from github and they didnt work. The code above is just a snippet from a larger object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit to address comment about lines catching up/overlapping**

One thing you can do is use a sine-function for your incrementing array. That is, divide the range of [0º,90º] into six parts, `[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75]`, then increment those degrees by one each time. Use the `sine` of these values to compute your radius.

Here's some code that will hopefully make that clearer.

```
var DEG_TO_RADIAN = Math.PI / 180; // convert degrees to radian
var minRadius = 100;
var maxRadius = 340;
var degrees = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75];
var radius = new Array(6);

function incrementArray(){
  degrees.forEach(function(d, i){
    degrees[i] = (degrees[i] + 1) % 90; // so it's always between [0,90]
    var radian = degrees[i] * DEG_TO_RADIAN;
    var sine = Math.sin(radian); 
    // bound the radius so it's between min and max allowed radius
    // and convert to integer value.
    radius[i] = Math.round(minRadius + sine * (maxRadius - minRadius));
  });

  console.log("Radius = " + radius.join(","))
}

setInterval(incrementArray, 50)
```

Here is a [bl.ock with a sample animation](http://bl.ocks.org/adilapapaya/f2467e769bbb7da62bdb) and [the corresponding gist](https://gist.github.com/adilapapaya/f2467e769bbb7da62bdb).

---

**Previous answer. Please ignore...doesn't address the specific issue.**

*This works, but you will need to modify it to do all the other extra stuff you're doing.*

```
arr = [100, 150, 220, 280, 310, 330];
increments = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
allowedMax = 332; // reset to 100 once we hit this

function incrementArray(){
  arr.forEach(function(d, i){
    arr[i] += increments[i];
    if(arr[i] > allowedMax){
      arr[i] = 100;
    }
  });
  arr.sort(); // sort ascending.
  console.log(arr) // print so we can see that it makes sense
}

// increment every 1 second
setInterval(incrementArray, 1000)
```

Comment: Yes but you have missed my point about the fact that the numbers catch up with each other. If you plotted these numbers as widths on the rings, you would see that the smalest one is increasing much faster than any of the others and therefore there are huge gaps. This is the exact issue I am having. I would like to maintain the easing effect, as in the rings get closer together as they get to the edge but i dont know how to achieve this without causing the other rings to eventually catch up...

Comment: Ah, sorry...missed that part~! See my updated answer above.

Comment: This is much better, but is it possible to add limits? I need to start the value at 100, and max it out at 340. Also, can you make sure as soon as it hits the maximum level, it is reset to 100. The figures dont need to be precise, just around 100 and around 340... But ideally, I would like the limits to be editable

Comment: @BenCarey see updated answer above. Instead of computing the radius using `sine * maxRadius`, you compute it using `minRadius + sine * (maxRadius - minRadius). I added a link to a [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/adilapapaya/f2467e769bbb7da62bdb) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will implement this and accept the answer if it works with my app :-)